# Python equivalent of Matlab's resample()

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing

Is there a python function that achieves resampling in the way MATLAB's resample() does? I've looked into scikits.samplerate's resample function but I'm not quite getting similar results.

Comment: Code please, in both languages, showing what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a blog '[Audio Resampling in Python](http://signalsprocessed.blogspot.com/2016/08/audio-resampling-in-python.html)' about this. Both resampy and scipy.signal have a resample function implementation in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

The best function that is equivalent to MATLAB resample is as such:

MATLAB:

```
resample(  Data_Low_Freq_v, Upsample_n ,Downsample_n );
```

Python:

```
import scipy.signal as ssg    
ssg.resample_poly(Data_Low_Freq_v, Upsample_n, Downsample_n)
```